# Jasmine + Angular testing with Typescript: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test the following service and seem to be having trouble matching the mock response:

```
public getCustomerDetails(customerID:string): ng.IPromise<ICustomerDetails> {
    return this.testService.getCustomerDetails(customerID).then((customerResponse:ICustomerResult) => {

        var customer = customerResponse.customers;

        var customerDetailsResult:ICustomerDetails = {
            customerNumber: customer.displayCustomerNumber,
            name: customer.name,
            userId: customer.buId,
            customerType: customer.type,
            address: customer.displayAddress
        };

        return customerDetailsResult;
    });
}
```

Here is the Jasmine code:

```
describe('CustomerService', () => {
    var mockTestService: any = {};
    var $q: ng.IQService;
    var createCustomerDetailsService;
    var customerDetailsService;
    var createResolvedPromise;
    var resolvePromises;

    var serviceResponse = {
        customerNumber: 'string',
        name: 'name',
        userId: 'buId',
        customerType: 'type',
        address: 'displayAddress'
    };

    var rootScope;

    beforeEach(() => {
        module('app.customer');

        inject(( _$q_, $injector) => {
            this.$q = _$q_;
            rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

            createResolvedPromise = (result) => {
                return this.$q.when(result);
            };

            resolvePromises = () => {
                rootScope.$apply();
            };

            createCustomerDetailsService = () => {
                return new app.customer.CustomerService(
                    mockRnsService);
            };
        });

    });


    it('WILL search by customer ID and return a customers details', () => {
        var searchResponsePromise;

        mockTestService.getCustomerDetails = jasmine.createSpy("getCustomerDetails").and.callFake(createResolvedPromise);
        customerDetailsService = createCustomerDetailsService();
        searchResponsePromise = customerDetailsService.getCustomerDetails('12345678');
        resolvePromises();

        expect(searchResponsePromise).toEqual(serviceResponse);
    });

});
```

The error I'm getting is:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'customer.displayCustomerNumber')`

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createResolvedPromise` sets up `getCustomerDetails` to return a promise with the value of the parameter that you pass in - in this case `'12345678'`. This means that the value of `customerResponse` is `'12345678'`. So `customer` which takes it's value from `customerResponse.customers` is undefined as there is no property `customers` on a string. So the error happens as you are trying to evaluate `customer.displayCustomerNumber` because `customer` is undefined.

Comment: Thankyou @TomDoesCode, that makes sense. Really appreciate your help!!